# Perl - How to split a file into smaller files

Tags: perl

I need advice how to make a perl program that will be able to split the file into smaller files using a number line.

for example:

```
perl split.pl --file="data.txt" --numberLine=2
```

input

data.txt:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
```

output

data1.txt

```
line1
line2
```

data2.txt

```
line3
line4
```

or

```
perl split.pl --file="data.txt" --numberLine=1
```

data1.txt

```
line1
```

data2.txt

```
line2
```

data3.txt

```
line3
```

data4.txt

```
line4
```

or
    perl split.pl --file="data.txt" --numberLine=3

data1.txt

```
line1
line2
line3
```

data2.txt

```
line4
```

Answer (score 5):

split:

```
system("split -l 2 $file");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;
use File::Basename;
my ($length, $file);

my $res= GetOptions ("numberLine=i" => \$length,
                      "file=s" => \$file);

my ($name,$path,$suffix) = fileparse($file,("\.txt","\.dat"));

open(my $fh,$file) || die "$file $!";

my $lc=0;
my $outfh=undef;
while(<$fh>) {
    if (($lc % $length) == 0) {
            my $n=int($lc/$length)+1;
            open($outfh,">$name$n.txt") || warn "$name$n.txt $!";
            }
    $lc++;
    print $outfh $_;
    }
```

Alternatively, here is how to do it as a one liner.  You just set the "numberLines" yourself in the script line and supply the filename(s) as args

```
perl -n -e 'print; unless (($.-1)%2){$n++;open(F,">data$n.txt")} print F $_' data.txt
```

Comment: A few things I noticed, please take this as constructive criticism: (1) The `vars` pragma is unneccessary since globals can be declared with `our`. But why do you even need global variables? (2) The suffixes for `fileparse` are treated as regexes, not as strings, so `.` should really be escaped. (3) Instead of manually counting lines, you can use the `$.` variable. (4) It isn't neccesary to `close` a filehandle prior to reopening it, unless you want to reset the `$.` counter. (5) You can't `<F>` from a write-only filehandle.

Comment: 1) altered ``vars`` to ``my``  2) escaped dots 3) left in the counter in the long version as it is possibly clearer 4) removed close 5) the one liner was batshit wrong, corrected now.  Thanks @amon !

Answer (score 0):

```
 sed -e '1,2wdata1.txt' -e '3,$wdata2.txt' data.txt
```